# Python Inheritance and Calling a Method

Tags: python, inheritance, methods

I am trying to call a method that will return the flavors of an Ice Cream Stand. Below is my code:

```
class Restaurant:
    """Defining Restaurants"""
    def __init__ (self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):

        """Initializing a restaurant name and cuisine type"""
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        self.number_served = 545

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        """Describing the restaurant"""
        print(self.restaurant_name.title() + " serves " + self.cuisine_type.title() + ".")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        """Stating the restaurant is open"""
        print(self.restaurant_name.title() + " is now open.")

    def set_number_served(self):
        """Method that sets the number served"""
        set_number_served = 430
        print("This restaurant has served " + str(set_number_served) + " customers.")

    def restaurant(self):
        """Statement showing how many customers have been served"""
        print("This restaurant has served " + str(self.number_served) + " customers.")

    def increment_number_served(self):
        self.number_served += 432
        print("This restaurant has served " + str(self.number_served) + " customers.")

class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):
    """Represents an ice cream stand"""
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type, flavors):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        self.flavors = flavors

    def flavors(self):
        """Flavors of ice cream"""
        flavors = ['chocolate', 'vanilla', 'strawberry']
        for flavor in flavors:
            return flavor.title()

my_IceCreamStand = IceCreamStand('West Ice Cream', 'Dessert', 'multiple')
my_IceCreamStand.flavors()
```

The error I am receiving is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ice_Cream_Stand.py", line 45, in <module>
    my_IceCreamStand.flavors()
```

Any ideas?

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you shadow your method with an attribute of the same name. In your `__init__` you do `self.flavors = flavors` and you initialize it with

```
my_IceCreamStand = IceCreamStand('West Ice Cream', 'Dessert', 'multiple')
```

So now, any time your instance uses `self.flavors`, it will return `'multiple'`, which is a string. You then try to call it like a function using `()`, and as the error says, strings are not callable.

Change the name of the attribute or of the method, but they shouldn't have the same name.

Comment: Awesome, that was it! Thank you a ton!